# Why does this class run?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've been playing with my codes a little for a while, and this one is not about a bug or anything, but i just don't understand why class main() runs without needing to initialize it...

```
class vars():
    var1 = "Universe!"
    var2 = "Oscar!"
    var3 = "Rainbow!"

class main():
    print (vars.var1)
    def __init__(self):
        print (vars.var2)
        print (vars.var3)
```

But yes, thank you very much for reading.

Comment: It simply looks at the classes and sees that they are valid python. There is no need to initialize, although nothing will happen unless you do.

Comment: what do you mean *without needing to initialize it* ? You should only get `vars.var1` printed, right? Exactly what do you see and what do you need answer for?

Comment: ...why do you think it won't run?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unlike many other languages, class body is an executable statement in Python and is executed immediately as the interpreter reaches the `class` line. When you run this "program":

```
class Foo:
    print("hey")
```

it just prints "hey" without any `Foo` object being created.

The same applies to the function definition statement `def` (but not to function bodies). When you run this:

```
def foo(arg=print("hi")):
    print("not yet")
```

it prints "hi", but not "not yet".

Answer (score 7):

When a class is created, Python executes all of the code directly inside the class declaration in a new namespace.  This is so that any variables created in the class (most commonly methods, created by ordinary function declarations like `def foo(self...)`) are attached to the class rather than being global.

But the code still runs immediately.  If it calls `print()` or does something else which creates a visible side effect, that will happen now, not when the class is instantiated (called to create a new instance).  If you need something to happen when the class is instantiated, write an `__init__()` method instead.

Answer (score 1):

`main` is a `class` not a function. Thus the code contained in the `class` declaration runs immediately because all statements are executed as they appear in code. As a method declaration is reached, it's bound to the class as a member, so in a way methods execute as well but are not called.

Answer (score 1):

When Python read your code, it looked into class vars and defined all the variables. Then, it went into class main and executed the code there, as well as defining **init**. Python just executes whatever which is not in a function definition.