# weird behaviour: python application using tkfiledialog, dialog doesn't open a 2nd time

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I have a python application controlling a testbed for some technical device. Python itself doesn't use a GUI, everything is displayed in a browser and we use socket connections to communicate.

There is one point, where the operator has to save a protocol file and we need a dialog to select this file. I decided to use the Tkinter plugin for that purpose.

So now I have a small module `dialogs.py` for all the GUI stuff, which is probably quite overdone, but nvm. Here it is:

```
from Tkinter import Toplevel, Tk
from tkFileDialog import asksaveasfilename, askopenfilename, askdirectory

class Getter:

    def _create(self):
        self.gui = Tk() # create instance
        self.gui.wm_attributes('-topmost', 1) # ensure it is on top
        self.gui.geometry('0x0+0+0') # minimize

    def _destroy(self):
        self.gui.destroy() # destroy instance

    def get(self):
        pass


class SaveFileGetter(Getter):

    def get(self, ext=None, dir=None, file=None):
        self._create()
        filename = asksaveasfilename(parent=self.gui, defaultextension=ext, initialdir=dir, initialfile=file) # show the dialog
        self._destroy()
        return filename
```

And then there is somewhere in another module:

```
from helpers.dialogs import SaveFileGetter

# lots of code

def saveOnRemote(self):
    # code
    protocolFilePath = SaveFileGetter().get(ext='.html')
    # more code

# even more code
```

When the application runs for the first time everything is fine. But when run the 2nd time, the program reaches the line

```
self.gui = Tk()
```

and nothing happens. No dialog does open, there is no exception, no beeping, nothing. The program is so to speak frozen. The CPU usage stays high, so obviously there is something happening in the background, but the application itself doesn't move forward.

To make things weird: If I use Toplevel() instead of Tk() the dialog does open multiple times, but occasionally there is an exception at the same line of code:

```
self.gui = Toplevel()
```

The error displayed is:

```
File "C:/path/to/my/project/somepythonfile.py", line 324, in saveOnRemote
protocolFilePath = SaveFileGetter().get(ext='.html')
File "C:/path/to/my/project/dialogs.py", line 22, in get
self._create()
File "C:/path/to/my/project/dialogs.py", line 8, in _create
self.gui = Toplevel()
File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 2129, in __init__
BaseWidget.__init__(self, master, 'toplevel', cnf, {}, extra)
File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 2086, in __init__
(widgetName, self._w) + extra + self._options(cnf))
TclError: out of stack space (infinite loop?)
```

And for master weirdness, this may happen at any time it seems, at the third execution, at the tenth ... or later. Later in operation it will be used maybe once per hour, but I can't accept that as the operator would have to restart the program to make it work properly again and btw cannot save the protocol file at that moment.

I already wrote a little standalone script, requesting the save file dialog in an endless loop. Everything works as wanted using Tk() or Toplevel(), even without the `self.gui.destroy()` part.

So there must be something else in my application causing this behaviour. Of course I cannot show the whole code (too much, company work etc.) and I imagine it's hard to guess for you. None of my colleagues has a clue, I myself just started the 3rd month of being a software developer and am clueless as well.

So if you have the tiniest approach of an idea, what could be the reason, please tell me.

---

Inspired by rolika's comment I changed my Getter class to:

```
class Getter:

    def __init__(self):
        self.gui = Tk()
        self.gui.wm_attributes('-topmost', 1)
        self.gui.geometry('0x0+0+0')

    def __del__(self):
        self.gui.destroy()
```

Unfortunately it doesn't change anything visibly.

Comment: The recursion error is the clue you need to investigate further.  If your code is written properly tkinter will never do that. My guess is that there's code  in the `__init__` of `SaveFileGetter` that is causing the  problem.

Comment: @BryanOakley: Note that neither `SaveFileGetter` nor `Getter` have (explicit) `__init__` methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for the records, although it is no real answer, but a solution. I'm using `wxPython` instead of `Tkinter` now. So this is my Getter class:

```
import wx

class Getter():

    def __init__(self):

        self.app = wx.App()
        self.frame = wx.Frame(None, -1, style=wx.CAPTION, size=(0, 0))

    def __del__(self):

        self.app.Destroy()

    def saveFile(self, ext='*.*', dir='', file='', title=''):

        dialog = wx.FileDialog(self.frame, title, dir, file, '|'+ext, wx.FD_SAVE | wx.FD_OVERWRITE_PROMPT)
        dialog.ShowModal()
        return dialog.GetPath()
```

And it works, every time.

Answer (score 0):

This really is just a suggestion:

Have you tried it without supplying a parent? Parent is optional, and if you don't supply, the dialog pops up over your app's root window.

Please see it here: http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/tkFileDialog.html

Comment: I guess I tried it before, but did it again right now, to be sure. Without supplying a parent, the dialog appears at the first execution. At the following executions, nothing happens and the program continues. The thing is: There is no app's root window, so there is a `Tk` instance generated automatically when calling the `asksaveasfilename` and the same weird stuff happens :-)

Comment: Another suggestion:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31839816/why-does-this-class-run

It would explain at least why it runs the first time.

Comment: Ok, I'm now using a constructor and deconstructor for my Getter class, but it doesn't help.